# netbeans: override and commit

Tags: svn, netbeans, synchronization, merge, commit

I'm getting really frustrated with synchronizing in netbeans (v6.9) - I can't fathom out how to do an eclipse style 'override and commit'.

The only way I can see to get my new code into the svn repository is to update my local copy with all the changes and then go back through and work out what the changes were, remove them, put my changes back in and commit.

Does anyone know where i'm going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using a version control system, you work by synchronizing local files with a repository, making changes to your local copy, then committing them to the repository. The following list describes various ways you can synchronize a project in NetBeans IDE, depending on your specific situation:

try this doc: http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/ide/subversion.html#synchronizing